# in php concatenation of '<' with any string becomes empty string

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I have a PHP socket connection. I send a request and receive its response. The response is in xml format and contains '<'. I want to concatenate strings and build one string of complete response. But when I put '<' at the beginning of string the whole string becomes null:

```
$s1 = 'hello';
$s2 = '<';
$s = $s2.$s1;
echo 's1: '.$s1.' s2: '.$s2.' s: '.$s;

output:
s1: hello s2: < s:
```

What should I do?

Comment: your code is working and giving same result. what's your problem then?

Comment: Use "View source" in your web browser to verify the `<` is sent correctly to the browser, then learn that a web browser specifically looks for a `<` character when it receives what it is told is html markup

Comment: I want the result to be s: <hello instead of empty string @anantkumarsingh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These is problem of TAGs that being skipped by Web Browser to display. You can display by converting '**<**' to "**&lt**".

PHP has built-in functions for such problem,

[String functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Search for 'HTML' in this page, you will get 4-5 functions that will help you.

Hope that helps !!